# PHP raphf extension version issues

Tags: php, composer-php, pear

I need to install php's raphf  extension (version 2.0.1 for Windows) to be able to use php's http extension,however,having followed the steps in the PECL documentation (installed the .ddl,added it to my ext file and added the extension to my php.ini file) the extension won't work.I get this error when I run the php --ini command

```
PHP Startup: raphf: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20210902
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
```

I understand that this is a version compatibility problem , however I have php 8.2 installed and the documentation says the extension should work with php 7.0.0 or newer.I also have PEAR 1.10.0 and the documentaion says anything above 1.4.0 should work.

There seems no other .ddl available for PHP 8.2 in particular and i really need the http extension to install a swagger bundle.

Comment: Keep in mind that this extension has seen its last updates in 2019, even before PHP 8.0 was released. Maybe you should search for alternatives? Also, if you need any help, please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how your problem is related to Composer

Comment: *“added it to my ext file and added the extension to my php.ini file”* Maybe users can figure out the issue if you share the paths of the files and their content.